# angular 5 provide shared service to imported module

Tags: angular

i have the following scenario. I have a shared service which i provide inside of appmodule and i also import a feature module in appmodule. From my understanding the shared service should be available in all modules and inside of the components of feature module. However it is not the case. An error keeps showing that the shared service is not defined when initiating the component of feature module.

I don't know what i should do now. I've been spending a long time finding a solution.

I hope you guys can help.

Error: 
Runtime Error: SharedService is not defined

Code:
inside app.module.ts

```
imports: [ FeatureModule ]
providers: [ SharedService]
```

inside feature.module.ts

```
declaration: [ ComponentA]
```

inside componentA.ts

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService){
}

click(){
    this.sharedService.function();
}
```

Comment: add code + error messages

Comment: Did you import module with shared service? or is it in app module

Comment: i import the feature module and provide the sharedservice inside of app.module.ts

Comment: You should not get `SharedService` not defined error but rather injector error about unsatisfied dependencies

Comment: hmm. I don't get what you mean. Are there other errors which are not shown? I verify by debug points that the component inside the feature module is loaded first, after that the sharedservice.

Comment: it's strange. Now the error shows that the provider is not defined in components declared in app.module